# Yii register form does not work

Tags: forms, yii, model, attributes, user-registration

I write a user form for register in the usermodel but I don't set rules.

the log is said:

```
04:24:19.273058    warning application 
Failed to set unsafe attribute "username" of "User".
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\protected\controllers\UserController.php
(59)
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\index.php (16)
04:24:19.273178 warning application 
Failed to set unsafe attribute "password" of "User".
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\protected\controllers\UserController.php
(59)
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\index.php (16)
04:24:19.273281 warning application 
Failed to set unsafe attribute "user_email" of "User".
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\protected\controllers\UserController.php
(59)
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\index.php (16)
04:24:19.273381 warning application 
Failed to set unsafe attribute "user_qq" of "User".
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\protected\controllers\UserController.php
(59)
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\index.php (16)
04:24:19.273478 warning application 
Failed to set unsafe attribute "user_tel" of "User".
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\protected\controllers\UserController.php
(59)
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\index.php (16)
04:24:19.273572 warning application 
Failed to set unsafe attribute "user_sex" of "User".
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\protected\controllers\UserController.php
(59)
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\index.php (16)
04:24:19.273665 warning application 
Failed to set unsafe attribute "user_xueli" of "User".
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\protected\controllers\UserController.php
(59)
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\index.php (16)
04:24:19.273761 warning application 
Failed to set unsafe attribute "user_hobby" of "User".
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\protected\controllers\UserController.php
(59)
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\index.php (16)
04:24:19.273855 warning application 
Failed to set unsafe attribute "user_introduce" of "User".
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\protected\controllers\UserController.php
(59)
in D:\xampp\htdocs\2013819\shop\index.php (16)
```

```
function actionRegister(){
        //实例化数据模型对象user
        $user_model = new User();
        /**
         * renderPartial不渲染布局
         * render会渲染布局 
         */
        //$this ->renderPartial('register');

        //性别信息
        $sex[1] = "男";
        $sex[2] = "女";
        $sex[3] = "保密";

        //定义学历
        $xueli[1] = "-请选择-";
        $xueli[2] = "小学";
        $xueli[3] = "初中";
        $xueli[4] = "高中";
        $xueli[5] = "大学";

        //定义爱好信息
        $hobby[1] = "篮球";
        $hobby[2] = "足球";
        $hobby[3] = "排球";
        $hobby[4] = "棒球";

        //如果用户有注册表单
        if(isset($_POST['User'])){
            //给模型收集表单信息
            //foreach($_POST['User'] as $_k => $_v){
            //    $user_model -> $_k = $_v;
            //}

            //上边的foreach，在yii框架里边有优化，使用模型属性attributes来进行优化
            //attributes 属性已经把foreach集成好了，我们可以直接使用
            $user_model -> attributes = $_POST['User'];

            //实现信息存储
            if($user_model -> save())
                $this ->redirect ('./index.php');  //重定向到首页
        }

        $this -> render('register',array('user_model'=>$user_model,'sex'=>$sex,'xueli'=>$xueli,'hobby'=>$hobby));
    }

<?php
/**
 * 用户模型model
 * 13-5-15 下午9:01   //时间通过netbeans快捷键  ctrl+j
 * 两个基本方法：
 * model
 * tableName
 */
class User extends CActiveRecord{
    //获得数据模型方法
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

//定义数据表名字
    public function tableName(){
        return "{{user}}";
    }

    //设置标签名字与数据库字段对应
    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'username'=>'用户名',
            'password'=>'密  码',
            'user_sex'=>'性  别',
            'user_qq'=>'qq号码',
            'user_hobby'=>'爱  好',
            'user_xueli'=>'学  历',
            'user_introduce'=>'简  介',
            'user_email'=>'邮  箱',
            'user_tel'=>'手机号码',
        );
    }

    /*
     * 实现用户注册表单验证
     * 在模型里边设置一个方法，定义具体表单域验证规则
     */
     /*
    public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('username','required','message'=>'用户名必填'),
            array('password','required','message'=>'密码必填'),
        );
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must NOT comment out the `rules()` function.

In it, you MUST set the attributes to safe, to allow Yii to copy the fields from the form to model:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('username, password, user_sex, user_qq, 
               user_hobby, user_xueli, user_introduce, 
               user_email, user_tel', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

See also: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/